# Specify devel branch for ner merge request

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

We have in our project more development branches based on the same code base, then we are creating features branches which are merged into corresponding devel branches.

```
                      /Feaure1
      /--develI--B--C/
---A-/
     \                 /Feature2
      \--develII--X--Y/
                 \
                   \ DevelIII--Q--R\
                                    \Feature3
```

When I push new commits in Feature3 to the git(lab) new button "New Merge Request" appears. But this merge request is to Devel2 branch instead of Devel3. How can I set in git(lab) which branch is my "parent" branch?

The feature branch was created on DevelIII branch in console (git checkout -b) Is it a git or gitlab feature?

Thanks!